# How to convert timecode string to seconds

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

With the duration values given as a list of strings:

```
durations = ['00:00:59:35','00:00:55:18', '00:01:04:28']
```

I need to get the integer values representing the seconds.

Attempt to do it with:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
result = parse('00:00:59:35')
```

Getting a traceback: `ValueError: Unknown string format`.

Is there a way to convert this string format to the seconds?

Comment: can you please give a sample expected output?

Comment: What is the format of the durations?

Comment: What are each of the numbers? hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds ?

Comment: Do you want to parse the duration and get only seconds or you want to convert everything to seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the format is as @tdelaney said. And if you want the seconds then you can use this list comprehension.

```
durations = ['00:00:59:35','00:00:55:18', '00:01:04:28']
secs = [int(d.split(":")[2]) for d in durations]
```